# Logging file is empty

Tags: spring, logging, boot

In my pet spring boot app I got logging properties like:

```
logging.file.name=Y:/Logs/app.log
logging.level.com.example.demo=debug 
logging.level.org.springframework=info
logging.pattern.console= %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n
logging.pattern.file= %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%
```

File app.log is created , but its emply, besides console log is works and gives all logs messadges, what's I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding **%n** after **%msg** in the file pattern property, like this:

> logging.pattern.file=%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %msg%n
> logging.file.name=C:\\yourpath\\yourfile.log